# How to remove obejct from multi level array in nodejs using mongo?

Tags: mongodb

{
"_id" : ObjectId("52f504bb2f9dd91186211537"),

```
"Data": {

    "Stage": {

        "FirstArray": [
            {
                "Name": "FirstLevelArray-FirstObject",
                "_id": ObjectId("5fe1a5fa2d8e360ac4093b7e"),
                "SecondArray": [
                    {
                        "Name": "1-SecondLevelArray-FirstObject",
                        "_id": ObjectId("5fe1a7a52d8e360ac4093b81")
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "1-SecondLevelArray-SecondObject",
                        "_id": ObjectId("5fe1a7a52d8e360ac4093b82")
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "FirstLevelArray-SecondObject",
                "_id": ObjectId("5fdc9dced45fa417d417c441"),
                "SecondArray": [
                    {
                        "Name": "2-SecondLevelArray-FirstObject",
                        "_id": ObjectId("5fde08564d28f313acc0c93b")
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "2-SecondLevelArray-SecondObject",
                        "_id": ObjectId("5fde08d64d28f313acc0c93c")
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}
This is the sample format of my code.
I want to delete this object { "Name": "2-SecondLevelArray-SecondObject", "_id": ObjectId("5fde08d64d28f313acc0c93c") } from this record.

I tried this query

model.update(
{ $and: [{ "_id": ObjectId("52f504bb2f9dd91186211537") }},
{"Data.Stage.FirstArray.SecondArray._id":ObjectId("5fde08d64d28f313acc0c93c")}] ,
{ $pull:{
"Data.Stage.FirstArray.$.SecondArray._id": ObjectId("5fe1a7a52d8e360ac4093b82")
}
},
{new:true,upsert:false})

```
How would I achieve this in MongoDB ?


Here is the expected result of find({"_id" : ObjectId("52f504bb2f9dd91186211537")}) after the update
```

EDIT: {
"_id" : ObjectId("52f504bb2f9dd91186211537"),

```
    "Data": {

        "Stage": {

            "FirstArray": [
                {
                    "Name": "FirstLevelArray-FirstObject",
                    "_id": ObjectId("5fe1a5fa2d8e360ac4093b7e"),
                    "SecondArray": [
                        {
                            "Name": "1-SecondLevelArray-FirstObject",
                            "_id": ObjectId("5fe1a7a52d8e360ac4093b81")
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "1-SecondLevelArray-SecondObject",
                            "_id": ObjectId("5fe1a7a52d8e360ac4093b82")
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Name": "FirstLevelArray-SecondObject",
                    "_id": ObjectId("5fdc9dced45fa417d417c441"),
                    "SecondArray": [
                        {
                            "Name": "2-SecondLevelArray-FirstObject",
                            "_id": ObjectId("5fde08564d28f313acc0c93b")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing wrong in your query, finding array with 5fde08d64d28f313acc0c93c id whereas doing $pull operator on different array that is with diff id 5fe1a7a52d8e360ac4093b82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model.update({ _id: ObjectId("52f504bb2f9dd91186211537"), Data.Stage.FirstArray:{ $elemMatch: { SecondArray:{$elemMatch:{"_id":ObjectId("5fde08d64d28f313acc0c93c")}}}}},
           { $pull:{ "Data.Stage.FirstArray.$.SecondArray":{"_id": ObjectId("5fde08d64d28f313acc0c93c") }}},{new:true,upsert:false})
```

Comment: If its working then please mark right this answer @PulakanamDivya

Comment: For Delete Case its Working

But in fetch case,how can i find particular in that sample Data

I tried this query to find   this  object {Name: "1-SecondLevelArray-SecondObject"}


Model.find({"Data.Stage.FirstArray.SecondArray.Name":"1-SecondLevelArray-SecondObject"},{"_id":1,"Data.Stage.FirstArray.$.SecondArray":1})

--this query is giving whole Record , i need only that object for fetch

Comment: Model.find({"Data.Stage.FirstArray:{ $elemMatch:{SecondArray:{ $elemMatch:{Name":"1-SecondLevelArray-SecondObject"}}}}},{_id:1,"Data.Stage.FirstArray":1}).
In find query you can't limit array obj but i think in aggregate you can use $project with array operators

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to filter out those with your given `Name` field

```
model.updateMany({}, {
    $set: { "Data.Stage.FirstArray.SecondArray": { $filter: {
        input: "$Data.Stage.FirstArray.SecondArray",
        as: "item",
        cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.Name", '2-SecondLevelArray-SecondObject' ] }
     } } },
});
```

Honestly, I'm not sure it will be working but it worths a try.

Comment: I tried, I'm getting error .Invalid query: Cannot create field 'SecondArray' in element {FirstArray:[{.....}